# Table Cell text with Jquery RowIndex

Tags: jquery

I'm filtering an Ajax loaded CSV after convert to HTML table, and the only way to filter the table rows is using the RowIndex.

```
var myVar = ($( "td:contains('sample')" ).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex);
```

With this script, I can find the number of the row containing the value "sample" in the column 3 of my table, so, I want to use this row number to access the text in column 2 in the same row.

I know how can I filter the Column 2, but no idea about what can I do to select only the row X - the same of "sample".

Anyone here can help?

Comment: `var tr=$( "td:contains('sample')" ).closest("tr")`, this will give you row you are looking for

Comment: you want to get the column number also?

Comment: You have to run `.each()` for `trs` and if found `sample` in any `td`, then get that `tr`

Comment: I just need the text in the other column. I have the row number, in this case, row 12, I need the text in this same row, but in a different column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like,

```
var columns = $( "td:contains('sample')" ).sibings("td").addBack();
columns.eq(0) //column 1
columns.eq(1) //column 2
.
.
```

Comment: I just try with siblings but my variable return "Object Object", you know why?

Comment: @ZecaNovaes What do you want to get? Is my answer not useful at your context?

Comment: I'm trying to use your answer, thank you for this, but I can't get the value that I want. What I need is, having two differents columns in the same row, be able to access the cells values in every column (filtering by the row number - that I have with my script)

Comment: @ZecaNovaes You can access its value by `columns.eq(0).text()`